# Identification of the background music played in episode 2 and 3 of Beyblade Season 1 English dubbed version

Tags: music, beyblade

I'm trying to find out the name or any identification of the background music played at:

- [01:05](https://youtu.be/2abVsiv8Edo?t=1m5s) in Episode 2 of Beyblade [Season 1](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Beyblade_(First_Anime_Series)) (English dub) from [original series](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Beyblade_%28original_series%29). It's played during the battle between [Kai](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Kai_Hiwatari) and [Tyson](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Tyson_Granger).
- [05:57](https://youtu.be/7e7fjtpYNwU?t=5m57s) in Episode 3 of the aforesaid season. The music plays during the conversation between Tyson and [Kenny](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Kenny) after a friendly battle between Tyson and [Max](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Max_Tate).

I did search on web but most of the time the results I get are either the Beyblade songs with lyrics, or links to Japanese ones, but I can't figure out the one needed.

Comment: Please note that you are referring to the English *dubbed* localization. Being a dubbed localization, the license might not include rights to the music and other scores. If you compare the [dub](https://youtu.be/2abVsiv8Edo?t=66) to the [original](https://youtu.be/hFpByF3RklM?t=95), you'll notice these differences. It's possible that these miscellaneous tracks were never included in the English Soundtrack.

Comment: I've been looking all over and those are the bgs I wanted to hear! It's some really senti music that brings back childhood memories. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the soundtrack for the English Dub is as such.
For example, others like you [have tried to ask and received a similar reply](http://worldbeyblade.org/Thread-Season-1-background-music).

The music for dubs seems like quite a collaboration from both Nelvana and the Japanese side, as referenced from [this thread](http://www.toonzone.net/forums/anime-forum/272264-nelvanas-dubs-beyblade-metal-fight-fusion-bakugan-music-expensive-2-print.html):

> Actually - aside from guitars/bass - there's only 1 piece where I used live instruments- and that was cello. The rest is all electronic acoustic.
>
> Beyblade was a really unique situation, because once Corus/Nelvana sorted out the initial details, I was working directly with the Japanese for the entire process and I'd literally just update Nelvana with what was happening every few weeks or so.
>
> The director was very specific about instrument choices (you'll notice there's very little synthesizer/electronica) and it's mainly traditional orchestra/acoustic instruments. I worked with a translator on the Japan side at D-rights and all the music requests/revisions and so on were through them. The schedule was so tight that they were animating an episode as I was composing it and then they'd edit video to score on many occasions. Very interesting!

It shows that it is definitely different from the original Japanese version, although it was for Metal Fight instead of the original Beyblade series, I suspect it is the same treatment.

You might try your luck trying to contact the guy who did it.

As for ***why*** you are looking into it, I am not sure. However, if you just want to listen to it, there is some guy who did some sort of compilation:

https://youtu.be/w_7460ppe2c
https://youtu.be/6fu-ONlAn64
https://youtu.be/UfB7IbP_uyE

And he credits Martin Kujac in his FAQ.

This is probably not sufficient as an answer, but also, it was too much to put into the comments.

I do not think that you will find your answer anywhere, and this question is probably not answerable, unless you contact Nelvana or the creator of said BGMs, as they are unnamed and uncatalogued.

Comment: Can you quote some relevant content from the threads? I can't tell where it says that it's a collab from both sides.

Comment: As requested, updated